# Find truth value of propositional function

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have this propositional function:

> $p(x,y):y-x=y+x^2$

and I have to find truth value for:

- $\forall{x}\exists{y}$ $p(x,y)$
- $\exists{y}\forall{x}$ $p(x,y)$

Set of all numbers is integer numbers $Z$.
I am not sure if this is the same or not. My solution for both is $0$. Is this two propositions the same?

Comment: Have you written this correctly?  As it stands, the $y's$ cancel and you just get $x=0,-1$ regardless of the value of $y$.

Comment: yes i written it correctly.

Comment: Then, presuming this is meant to hold over $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$ or something like that, then both statements are false.  No value of $y$ makes the statement $p(1,y)$ true, for example.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to write that we are in set $Z$, I correct it

Comment: To be clear:  a priori, the statements are inequivalent.  The second one is stronger.  For example, take the proposition $q(x,y):x+y=0$.  Then $\forall x \exists y\;q(x,y)$ is true but $\exists y \forall x \;q(x,y)$ is false.

Comment: So, for my function are the same and my solution is correct?

Comment: I don't know what "my solution for both is $0$" means in this context. Both statements are false.  I would not say that they are logically equivalent, unless you want to say that all false statements are logically equivalent.